# Form.Close isnt working in Windows CE 7

Tags: winforms, windows-ce, motorola-emdk

I have windows application that used to run on a Motorola Scanner that used Windows Mobile 6.1. We upgraded the scanner to a newer model which uses Window CE 7. The application has a login form and a main form. One the user is authenticated, the login form closes and the main form opens up as expected but whenever a date is changed on the main form , the login screen reappears. Its as though login.Close() isn't really closing the login form but actually pushing it to the background and its reappearing. This application used to work fine in the older scan gun. I tried searching for specific issues but to no use.

Comment: show the code where the login form is created and closed. It should be a modalform that is created in a using() block. You need to dispose it because on windows CE the GC keeps weak references for every form

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for but you can try to set the minimizebox property to false on the form as winmobile tends to not close application but send them to background instead. With that property to false, it will close it. Although it would be interesting to see your code because calling the close() statement on the form should close it...